# How can I create a fragment without overwrite on top of my activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I changed [this navigation drawer library](https://github.com/rudsonlive/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign) as [mikepenz's material drawer library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). Because first library was giving an error when I import a library that I want to use. But at the first library I was handling navigaiton drawer items click as below :

```
 case 2 :

     FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     Fragment mFragment = new PM_Fragment().newInstance(mHelpLiveo.get(position).getName());

     if (mFragment != null){
         mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, mFragment).commit();
     }

     break;
```

For my second library I got "R.id.container couldn't found" error. I guess container id is created inside of library. Because of this reason I'm trying to put an id to replace. So I put the first id of my activity_main layout as below:

```
case 2:
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragment = new PM_Fragment().newInstance(String.valueOf(position));

    if (mFragment != null) {
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment).commit();
    }

    break;
```

and my R.id.content_frame is coming from my activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/helloid"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"/>...
```

But when I click an item new fragment is written on top of my activity_main.xml layout. Here is the my screenshot :D

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Mike M , but this means I have to create navigation drawer for all fragments. Because navigation drawer is getting toolbar with this code : `new DrawerBuilder().withToolbar(toolbar)`. so if I create toolbar for each I also have to create navigation drawer.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't realized what you're trying to do when I first commented. That's why I deleted it. Ajinkya's on the right track. You need to add an empty ViewGroup in your `activity_main` layout to hold the Fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

content_frame is id of your main activity layout thats why it is happening use new relative layout and give it id content_frame

Answer (score 1):

I guess one of the problem is that you are inserting the fragment in a relative layout, while a frame layout would be more appropriate; thant I would suggest you to use the navigation view and the drawer layout Android widgets provided by Google instead of third party libraries, it is really easy to use them, if you need more information about navigation view and how to use it please tell me or refer to the official documentation

Here is a link to google developer page:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html

Comment: Neither of those suggestions addresses the OP's problem.

Comment: Actually putting an empty frame layout in the XML file provided as example and using it as container for the fragment transaction would solve the problem; the part of the layout that is now in the relative layout should be put in a different layout file, as you said, and loaded dynamically when the activity is started to be presented as "home" fragment, another thing is that in my opinion it would be better to use proper widgets, like drawer layout and navigation views, which have been thought for this particular situation; then you're right that my answer was not so focused on the problem

Comment: "putting an empty frame layout in the XML file provided as example and using it as container for the fragment transaction would solve the problem" - You should put something like that in the answer. As it stands, it sounds like you're saying that the problem is just that the OP is using a RelativeLayout instead of a FrameLayout.